# Ubuntu 20.04 not shutting down

Tags: shutdown

When I try to shut down my pc, it first sends me to the login page where it hangs for a few seconds, and then I get the following logs:

```
Stopping permit user sessions...
[Ok] Stopped permit user sessions.
```

Edit:
I got some logs using journalctl

```
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@125.service: Succeeded.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/125.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 125.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Stopping Permit User Sessions...
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: systemd-user-sessions.service: Succeeded.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Stopped Permit User Sessions.
jun 24 21:25:42 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitiga>
jun 24 21:29:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitiga>
jun 24 21:34:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitiga>
jun 24 21:39:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitiga>
jun 24 21:44:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitiga>
jun 24 21:49:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitiga>
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Job poweroff.target/start timed >
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: Timed out starting Power-Off.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Job poweroff.target/start failed>
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: Forcibly powering off: job timed out
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-logind[1062]: Operation 'shutdown' finished.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: Shutting down.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
jun 24 21:54:31 Q dnsmasq[1412]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
jun 24 21:54:31 Q NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1593028471.8127] caught SIGTER>
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-journald[456]: Journal stopped
lines 994-1016/1016 (END)
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@125.service: Succeeded.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/125.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 125.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Stopping Permit User Sessions...
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: systemd-user-sessions.service: Succeeded.
jun 24 21:24:33 Q systemd[1]: Stopped Permit User Sessions.
jun 24 21:25:42 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jun 24 21:29:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jun 24 21:34:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jun 24 21:39:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jun 24 21:44:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jun 24 21:49:58 Q systemd-resolved[981]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Job poweroff.target/start timed out.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: Timed out starting Power-Off.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Job poweroff.target/start failed with result 'timeout'.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: Forcibly powering off: job timed out
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-logind[1062]: Operation 'shutdown' finished.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd[1]: Shutting down.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
jun 24 21:54:31 Q dnsmasq[1412]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
jun 24 21:54:31 Q NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1593028471.8127] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
jun 24 21:54:31 Q systemd-journald[456]: Journal stopped
```

running

```
dmidecode -s bios-version
```

returns F42a

I have an aorus x470 ultra gaming cf

amd ryzen 3700x

rtx 2070

Comment: Could be waiting for a timeout. Next time, wait for 31 minutes, then after reboot `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you log messages.

Comment: Do I have to wait 31 minutes or can I also hold the power button?

Comment: Wait 31 minutes for the system to let any 30 minute timeouts expire. Do not use the power switch.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer. Also, rather than the "31 minute" process, just shutdown, then hit the ESC key, and watch the log on the screen and see where it hangs up or errors out.

Comment: Read the log yourself. There are several delays just from the timestamps. Any log entry containing "`Time out`" or "`Timed out`" ,etc. Treat these as separate problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, I just reinstalled the NVIDIA drivers which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Aorus x470 Ultra Gaming

You have BIOS version F42a.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F50, dated 11/27/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X470-AORUS-ULTRA-GAMING-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.